# Two links between 2 tables

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I have 2 tables in my database that I'm trying to design in mysql workbench.

1 table - Company

```
 1. ID
 2. Company
 3. Company_Number
 4. Created_Date
```

2 table - Employees

```
 1. ID
 2. Employee
 3. Company_Number
 4. Created_Date
```

I want to create a relationship between Company and Employees. 1 Company can have multiple employees. The problem is that I cannot make Company_Number as a primary key since those keys might duplicate since data will be dumped in daily. Also one employee can work for multiple employees but for each company he/she will have an additional row with data.

Is there a way to make 2 relationships between those two tables? 1 to 1 created_date - created_date & one to many company_number to company_number

Comment: The usual way to do that is a table `company_empoyee` with the columns `(companyid, employeeid)` (the combination of both are the primary key of that table, both are referencing the base tables). I don't see a reason why that would be a problem here. If you dump data (I didn't get that part), do that using a temporary table.

Comment: @Solarflare I'm trying to find the most common practices. Well by dumping I mean that everyday there would be a list of companies and workers working for all those companies added to the database that is why I did not know what a primary key should be since the data would be quite similar everyday.

Comment: It's an interesting semantic question.  An employee is not an employee until the relationship between an organization and a person is complete.  I would have to agree with Solarflare on this solution.  The structures you have proposed are very "closed" and will not allow for the occasion that an employee is no more.  After reading your comment above, I have a question:  is this more of a warehousing effort?

Comment: Basically I'm gathering companies that have the same index and in employees I will store names of those employees (officers) and position in the company. Each employee can work for multiple companies and can have different positions.

Comment: Do I understand you correctly? You will add the same company several times in your company table for each new import? Do NOT do that. If you absolutly have to, you can create a `history`-table, where you add a row for each import. But the company table should have just one row for one company. Same for employee. And the `company_employee` will allow you to have multiple connections: add eg `(1,1), (1,2), (2,2)` to your table, then worker `1` works for company `1`, and worker `2` works for company `1` and `2`. (so a company can have multiple workers and a worker can work for multiple companies)

Comment: @Solarflare Data will be downloaded daily and only data from the newest day will be used and all older dates are for backup. There will be same companies in company table but for different days for each day companies will be unique if that makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

Delete `Company_Number` from `Employee` table, then create a new table, let's say `WorksFor` in which you have 2 columns `ID_Company,ID_Employee`,`created_table` and make those 2 columns as primary key

Comment: Additionally, having some flag status column to identify if the employee was active or terminated.

Answer (score 0):

A inner join on company_number  give you the relation

```
select c.* e.*
from Company as c
INNER JOIN Employees as e on e.company_number = c.Company_number
```

and you can create the relation on the two column also

```
select c.* e.*
from Company as c
INNER JOIN Employees as e on 
       (e.company_number = c.Company_number and e.Created_Date = c.Created_Date)
```